# How to convert binary bits into array

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary

In my project i want to convert binary bits into array .

For example :

binary value of

```
a= dec2bin(1) = 0001
```

but i want to convert it into array and store like this

```
a=[0 0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str2num` of the transposed array `a`:

```
a = dec2bin(1,4);

out = str2num(a')';
```

This way, each element of the string `a` is individually converted into a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bitand`, e.g.,

```
>> bitand(1, 2.^(7:-1:0)) > 0

ans =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Or

```
bitand(10, 2.^(7:-1:0)) > 0

ans =

 0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

And, if you need to calculate many powers of two to include for an arbitrary number, you can use `ceil(log2(theNumber))`